# Disable default css settings of text in Android

Tags: android, html, css, text

Okay, so I am creating this mobile website where I am trying to *change the font-size and color of some text*. Now, I have tested my code on my PC, iOS and Android (using Chrome browser) and only on the Android there seems to be a problem. When using an imported CSS document some settings will not change, but if I type then in directly into the element using the "style" attribute everything works.

#### Font

The font-size seems to have different levels as when I type in:

```
font-size: 31px;
```

it gives me this:

## Hello

However if I were to change it to:

```
font-size: 30px;
```

the font size will now be like this:

Hello

#### Color

Also, the color on Android never seems to change as the color is always black. I have tried changing it to both other dark and bright colors without any success (note the colors are changing on both my PC and on iOS).

#### Override

I am thinking that there might be some sort of snippet of code which would override these default settings. If anyone of you have found one when importing CSS to a PHP/HTML doc or have any other solution it would gladly be appreciated!

Comment: i think your style is overwritten by some other class or css styling try: font-size: 30px !important;

Comment: Will try it! Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It did solve the color issue I had, don't really know why only Android overwrote the css and not the others. However as my font-size is embedded in my jQuery it complicates it a bit. i will look for a solution for adding "!important" in jQuery and hope that will be the solution I am looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: I will make it an answer so that others can notice the solution.... btw. it is not Android this is HTML/CSS it can be that a class attached to a div tag or whatever is overwritting your styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your style is overwritten by some other CSS class or css styling use:

**font-size: 30px !important;**

thereby your styling will be applied over all other stylings thereby overwriting all predefined stylings